# if condition in "mysql ON"

Tags: mysql, join

In my website, I want to delete a series delete. that is, if main category is deleted, all the associated sub categories and sub-sub categories will delete. For that I wrote the below query,

```
UPDATE tabel1 AS t1
JOIN tabel2 AS t2 ON t2.foreignkey = t1.primarykey
JOIN tabel3 AS t3 ON t3.foreignkey = t2.primarykey
JOIN tabel4 AS t4 ON t4.foreignkey = t3.primarykey
SET t1.status = 'deleted',
 t2.status = 'deleted',
 t3.status = 'deleted',
 t4.status = 'deleted'
WHERE
 t1.primarykey = '1'
```

This query works well is there are corresponding foreign keys in each table. Suppose if the last table is for storing images. and it is not compulsory that one should add images for table 3 data. So if use the above query, It fails when found a table3 data with no corresponding table4 image data. But I need to delete that table 3 data too. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Did you read the `[delete]` tag's excerpt? It clearly says "*This tag is deprecated! Please use a more specific tag instead.*" Please read tags more carefully in the future. Thank you.

Comment: You will always need some kind of explicit `JOIN` condition in the `ON` clause, otherwise you can't identify which row is corresponding to the other tables.

Comment: I added `left join` instedd of `join` and the issue is fixed.. :)